# quarkus custom bean annotation "creating" proxies even with Singleton scope

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

I have a java library that I want to use inside a quarkus application, this library has a custom annotation that I want to use for bean loading so I wrote a quarkus extension and tried the [BeanDefiningAnnotationBuildItem](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions#bean-defining-annotations) approach.

Extract from the extension deployment module:

```
    static DotName OP_RULE_ANNOTATION = DotName.createSimple(OpRule.class.getName());
    static DotName SINGLETON = DotName.createSimple(Singleton.class.getName());

    @BuildStep
    void additionalBeanAnnotations(BuildProducer<BeanDefiningAnnotationBuildItem> beanDefiningAnnotations) {
        beanDefiningAnnotations.produce(new BeanDefiningAnnotationBuildItem(OP_RULE_ANNOTATION, SINGLETON, false));
    }
```

The annotation is correctly detected and beans are loaded but when I try to inject them they are wrapped by a proxy and it looks like the Singleton scope is ignored.

Does anyone have any hint on how I can debug this?

update:
While adding tests to the extension I also added a test to ensure that those classes would have not been wrapped by a Proxy and it passed, I do not have any special config on the application (that I know of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by dev-mode monitoring, disabling it with this property solves the issue:

`quarkus.arc.dev-mode.monitoring-enabled`

https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-arc_quarkus.arc.dev-mode.monitoring-enabled